# Removing a key from parent object with jq

Tags: json, command-line, jq

How to exclude some items using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)? My JSON content has extra items I don't need (upwards of 500MB) and if I could trim those it reduces it to 1MB.

```
{
  "pages": {
    "elems": { ... stuff ... }
  },
  "actions": {
    "pages": { ... stuff ... }
  }
}
```

I want to delete the 1st level `pages` entire object and key, but retain the lower level `pages` intact. Expected Output:

```
{
  "actions": {
    "pages": { ... stuff ... }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Using the builtin function `del`:

```bash
$ jq 'del(.pages)' myfile.json
{
  "actions": {
    "pages": {
      "stuff": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/nwxNZ7LOY6)

To remove all pages everywhere, instead of just the outer level, you would use something like

```bash
$ jq 'del(.. | .pages?)' myfile.json
{
  "actions": {}
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/O76mi-VYRs)

Comment: If the key has a hyphen, then something like this needs to be one `jq 'del(.["log-driver"]) `

Comment: Is there a way to remove multiple keys from an object other than jq 'del(.k1)|del(.k2)|del(.k3)', ie using just 1 del call?

Answer (score 0):

Since your input file is quite large, it might be worthwhile using jq 1.5's streaming parser:

```
jq -n --stream '
  fromstream(inputs|select((length == 2 and .[0][0] == "pages")|not))
' input.json
```